# Why does the input not print out

Tags: java

I just want it to display my name.  It worked in a different code but I cut out the parts that were supposed to say the name.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ComputePay
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      String name;

         System.out.print("Please enter your First and Last name >> ");
         input.nextLine();
         name = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Thank you, " + name);
   }
}
```

Comment: Try to remove that line `input.nextLine();`

Comment: That worked.  But what if I want to add more lines with ints or doubles or strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do your `input.nextLine();` for the first time, you don't save the result to any variable. So you are loosing the value that the user entered before.

If you just remove that line then `name = input.nextLine();` will successfully read the value and store it in the variable *name*.

If you want to read in multiple values just repeat that process:

```
System.out.print("Please enter your first name >> ");
firstName = input.nextLine();
System.out.print("Please enter your last name >> ");
lastName = input.nextLine();
```